# How do I read an attribute below in CRM 2011 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am looking for the most simplest way of writing javascript code to read
an attribute(s) from the fetch xml given below. I have bumped into very complex ways of doing it. Can you suggest a quick and efficient way of doing it.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
    <entity name="bch_delegate">
        <attribute name="bch_delegateid" />
        <attribute name="bch_name" />
        <attribute name="createdon" />
        <order attribute="bch_name" descending="false" />
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="bch_signingauthority" operator="eq" uiname="Randy Claire" uitype="bch_signingauthority" value="{F391B13B-37ED-E411-AD95-0050569148C9}" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Please specify the execution method, for execute the above fecth xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to to this is to use the [XrmServiceToolkit](https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com) from Codeplex.
Sample see here [How use XRM Service Toolkit](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04c598c3-4208-42f7-8879-30e3d0e1eaaa/how-use-xrm-service-tollkit)

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery (keep in mind that jQuery 2.+ doesn't work with IE8, so I would use a 1.* version above 1.7). Here's an example:

```
//outer loop  
$(xml).find("a\\:Entity").each(function() {  
//inner loop  
$(this).find("a\\:KeyValuePairOfstringstring").each(function() {  
var xmlElement = $(this);  
var key = xmlElement.find("b\\:key").text();  
var value = xmlElement.find("b\\:value").text();  
//do something with the key and value  
});
```

Hopefully this helps. Here's the site it was found on:
http://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2013/01/21/fetchxml-jquery-in-a-dynamics-crm-2011-web-resource/